# Pulling AD group membership directly from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory

Auditors are here again, is it possible to query the members of Windows groups mapped to the SQL server?

There are over 100 groups with direct access to our database and I'd feel terrible asking our Wintel team to take screenshots of all 100 groups.

Comment: Not on the actual question but instead of taking screenshots, they might use some PowerShell commandlets to get the data conveniently...

Comment: Split this into two questions, which you should be able to find answers for individually: 1. How do you list all the AD groups that have access to your database? and 2. How you do you list the members of each of those AD groups?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [xp_logininfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-logininfo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Specifically with `@option='members'`.

Just to be clear, I think powreshell is a better tool for this. Get-ADGroupMember will do what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to query the server principals in SQL Server to list AD groups or users etc.

```
SELECT Name, type_desc
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE type = 'G' AND name NOT LIKE 'BUILTIN\Administrators'
ORDER BY name;
```

This query will then list the users in the group.

```
EXEC xp_logininfo @acctname = 'DomainName\GroupName', @option = 'members';
```